# New Azure VM says InvalidQueryParameterValue comp

Tags: azure, lamp, azure-virtual-machine

I created a new Azure VM, installed the LAMP stack, and when I visit the domain name in a browser, it serves the following error, which I am unable to find any information on through Google or Stack Overflow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:45ba52f4-0001-0086-13ed-e545cf000000
Time:2015-09-03T02:07:58.4816344Z</Message><QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue /><Reason /></Error>
```

When I use wget http://localhost while logged in through SSH, I get this error instead:

```
--2015-09-03 02:05:57--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 65 [text/html]
index.html: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘index.html’ (Permission denied).
```

The apache config for the default site is plain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I get this VM to start serving using Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error (when opening from Internet) is (most probably) showing that you do not try to access the **VM** URL, but another service instead (i.e. Azure storage service, or some other Azure service)

To make things more confusing for newcommers Microsoft has now 2 parallel types of services - one is called `classic` and the other is called `resource manager`. In order to give you best answer, I have to know how did you create your VM - using the `classic` or using the `resource manager` (or shortly ARM) mode. If it was the clasic, your VM should live in a domain something like: `mylinuxvm.cloudapp.net`. You can check this going to the management portal then selecting VM and checking its settings / properties. Is it is the case, the only thing you need to add is an [Endpoint for port 80](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/), so that Internet traffic coming on TCP port 80 will be redirected to your VM.

If it is an ARM VM, you need a [network security group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) rule that will send traffic on port 80 to your public IP Address, which has to be associated with the VM.

The second error:

> When I use wget http://localhost while logged in through SSH, I get
>   this error instead:
>
> --2015-09-03 02:05:57--  http://localhost/ Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost
>   (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 200 OK Length: 65 [text/html] index.html: Permission
>   denied
>
> Cannot write to ‘index.html’ (Permission denied).

You get because you are using `wget` instead of `curl`. The difference is that `curl` will just render the result in `stdout` while `wget` tries to *downalod and save* the contet. The error is quite clear:

> **Cannot write to ‘index.html’ (Permission denied).**

Which means you are executing the command in a folder to which you do not have write permission. This is usally the home of the **root** user when you do not do **sudo** before executing the command.

Comment: The addition of an endpoint for port 80 did the trick, thank you. As for the wget problem, that was just dumb on my part :) I should have known better.

Answer (score 21):

This can occur on the '[Static Website hosting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/)' feature if you point your CNAME to the wrong Azure server.

You must use the server DNS name that contains `web` in the name and not `blob`.

Comment: *Some of the available functionality may have changed since I originally wrote this so see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name*

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.